# Notifications to mobile in node js

Tags: node.js, push-notification

I have created some APIs in node js. I want to send notifications to user's mobile device from my node js api on some event. What are the prerequisite? What are the services I can use(For example can I use AWS SNS)? Please give me some proper reference links to study which are used anyone from you?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you mean by **notification** but if you mean **push notification**, then you need to talk to either apple / google's push notification server to handle this.

For iOS, you need to use APNS. Look into [this library](https://github.com/argon/node-apn).

For Android, you need to use GCM. Look into [this library](https://github.com/ToothlessGear/node-gcm).

If you meant something other than push notification, then you can use websocket but keep in mind there are restrictions around usage of websockets in mobile devices. You can look into [socket.io](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io).

Comment: Sorry. I meant push notifications. Thank you for the links.